Remove lines from text in a cell that match a set of words
Original text in a cell (e.g., A1):
apple

Apricot

Avocado


Apples

Banana
Blackberry

Cherry

Blueberry

Coconut


Cranberry



Date

Fig

A set of words in a cell (e.g., A2) that must be individually (delimiter ;) checked for matches on each line of text:
Apple;Banana;Cherry;Cranberry;Fig


Each individual word must exactly match (not case sensitive) the value of the line of text.

Expected text in a cell (e.g., A3):
The original text in a cell A1 consists of 26 lines, including blank ones. The result should match the following:


Lines 1, 10, 13, 20 and 26 should be removed after match checking.
Blank consecutive lines greater than 1 should be replaced with 1 blank line.
Blank lines before and after a non-blank value should be removed.


Apricot

Avocado

Apples

Blackberry

Blueberry

Coconut

Date


Try:
=LET(
  n,CHAR(10),
  s,SPLIT(A1,n),
  JOIN(n&n,FILTER(s,0=COUNTIF(SPLIT(A2,";"),s))))



Use Filter and Match
If you want the output to be multiple cells, you may use this:
=LET(a, TOCOL(SPLIT(A1,char(10))),
     b, TOCOL(SPLIT(A2,";")),
     FILTER(a, ISERROR(MATCH(ARRAYFORMULA(UPPER(a)), ARRAYFORMULA(UPPER(b)), 0))))

NOTE: UPPER was used to ignore case sensitivity by converting the texts into UPPERCASE. Alternatively, LOWER may be used the in same way which will convert the texts into lowercase.
Output: (multiple rows)








Apricot


Avocado


Apples


Blackberry


Blueberry


Coconut


Date



If you want the output to be just one cell, then add JOIN with CHAR(10) which is the char for line break.
=LET(a, SPLIT(A1,char(10)), 
     b, SPLIT(A2,";"), 
     JOIN(char(10)&char(10), FILTER(a, ISERROR(MATCH(ARRAYFORMULA(UPPER(a)), ARRAYFORMULA(UPPER(b)), 0)))))

Output: (single cell)

Apricot
Avocado
Apples
Blackberry
Blueberry
Coconut
Date


Feel free to ask anything about the answer posted above.
